# Meaning of the individual terms inside the linear function of a line

Tags: geometry, functions

> $$f(x) =f(a) \frac{x-b}{a-b}+f(b) \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

I get that the formula gives me a $y$ value for an $x$ value given two points: $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b))$.

However, what really is multiplying $f(a)$ by $\displaystyle\frac{x-b}{a-b}$ (as in the first term in the expression) doing 'towards' giving me $f(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking why $f$ is defined as it is in order to have the graph of $f$ passing through $(a,f(a)),(b,f(b))$?

Comment: I am asking about the intuition behind using (x-b)/(a-b) and multiplying it with f(a). It is unclear to me how, what is being done on the right hand of the equation, is allowing me to get the y value for an x.

Answer (score 1):

Any point in a straight line can be obtained as a linear combination of any two of its points, as you know $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b)),$ you can obtain any other point $(x,f(x))$ from observing that $x=\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$, and, hence $\lambda=\frac{x-b}{a-b}$, and this implies that $f(c)=\frac{x-b}{a-b}f(a)+\left(1-\frac{x-b}{a-b}\right)f(b)$. A little algebra for the term in parenthesis yields $\left(1-\frac{x-b}{a-b}\right)=\frac{a-x}{a-b}=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$.

Comment: im sorry, but could you please explain what λ means

Comment: @ZeeshanHassan, $\lambda$ is just a number. The proportion in which we need to combine $a$ and $b$ for the combination to equal $x$. This proportion can take any value, positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x-b}{a-b}$ means that you

1. Substract $b$ from $x$ to get $x-b$.
2. Substract $b$ from $a$ to get $a-b$.
3. Finally divide $x-b$ by $a-b$.

Therefore, if you compute the value of $\frac{x-b}{a-b}$ for $x=b$, you get $0$. And $1$ for $x=a$.